# Trigger truncate of an object

Tags: bulk-delete

Is it possible to trigger a truncate of an object in Salesforce? As a job etc.? Deleting the data from an object needs the Ids to be cached/stored and then deleted from the Salesforce. Even using "BulkAPI" is proving to be too slow for us. I have heard that we can Truncate an object in Saleforce which is quite fast. How do we do that?

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no way to `truncate` the object using `apex` or `API`. There is an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000k98UAAQ) posted which you can up-vote so that Salesforce takes this up to deliver this in future releases.

One other way of doing this would be to do this using `batch class` which won't require you to hold the `IDs` and will asynchronously delete the records from the object. You can go through [Asynchronous Apex](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/asynchronous_apex/async_apex_batch) trailhead module to get some further help on batch classes.

**Note :** The `auto number` fields won't get reset after deleting the records using batch apex i.e. using delete statements which does reset when truncating the object.

Comment: Thanks Vijay. We definitely need this feature through API. Upvoted the idea.

Comment: @user70782 Hope this gets delivered in future releases.

Comment: Hi @user70782 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.